# How to save ragged tensor as a file?

Tags: python, keras, tensor, ragged-tensors

How can I save a **ragged** tensor as a **file** on my disk and then reuse it in calculations opening it from the disk? Tensor consists of a nested array of numbers with 4 signs after the point. (I'm working in a Google Colab and using Google disk to save my files, I know only Python a little bit).

Here is my data:
I take this column "sim_fasttex" which is a list of lists of different length, reshape each of them according to "h" and "w" and collect all these matrices in one list, so finally it's going to be a ragged tensor of the shape (number of rows in initial table, variable length of a matrix, variable heigth of a matrix)

[image: initial data]
[image: Final array]

Comment: Please provide an example of the tensor you would like to serialize.

Comment: @KDecker I've added the description of the data and photos

Comment: What is the final approximate size of the array (I know its ragged). Maybe try `np.save(...)`.

Comment: @KDecker, thanks, I'll try! The amount of such observations is 21 thousands and each matrix is on average of the size 100×3000

Comment: From what I can tell you're using `float` data type. Given your numbers that equates to ~25.2 billion bytes, or ~25GB. If the array is very ragged (a lot of zeros) you may get some reduction from compression...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your context but,

You can save any object to a file using the `pickle` module. Like this

```py
import pickle

the_object = object

with open("a_file_name.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(the_object, f)
```

And later you can load that same object:

```py
import pickle
with open("a_file_name.pkl", "rb") as f:
    the_object = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: *TheBoneBlock, I've tried pickle, but it resulted in huge file weighting Gigabytes :(

Comment: Based on the description, if you have multiple rows each of approximate size (tens of values, thousands of values) it sounds like you literally have multiple gigabytes of data. You won't do much better than that.

Comment: @KDecker, oh, really?(( Then how people work with text analysis (NLP tasks), because the texts are huge and one need to store the embeddings of all of them somehow...

Comment: Performant computers. Namely, modern, fast, (readily available until covid), and reasonably cheap NVMe SSDs, expensive RAM, multicore hyperthreaded CPUs, Nvidia GPUs. Combined with good software (intelligent data loading and manipulation). // i.e. money and funding.